# Extract method dialog not opening in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to refactor any code by extracting a method whether from the 'Refactor Menu' or use the shortcut - 'ctrl + alt + M', the method directly gets crated with name as 'extracted' and the dialog box doesn't open wherein I could do changes to name and privacy of method. Also, it doesn't replace any duplicate code block with the method newly created. Is there any reason why the dialog box isn't opening?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature in the most recent version of IntelliJ Idea (2021.3). When you extract a method there is now a small settings icon next to the replaced code to click (or you can use CTRL+SHIFT+O) and see some of the old menu-style method extraction tools.